# How to convert date time to seconds

Tags: python

I have a df given like this:

```
            A 
0 03:32:57.565 2020-01-28
1 03:32:58.565 2020-01-28
2 03:32:59.566 2020-01-28
3 03:33:00.566 2020-01-28
4 03:33:01.569 2020-01-28
           ...
n 03:33:57.565 2020-01-28
```

I want to retrieve and store the accumulative of each row of each of these date times in seconds, excluding the date and the hours. Like this:

```
       A
0    7.565 
1    8.565
2    9.566
3    10.566
4    11.569
     ...
n    67.565
```

Comment: Why does `03:32:57.565` map to `7.565`, but `03:33:57.565` map to `60`?

Comment: You don't appear to be only dropping the hours and minutes; rows 0 through 4, at least, all look like offsets from 03:32:50. Row n, by this scheme, should be 67.565, not 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for the answer.

Here is how I solve it.

Maybe it is not the fastest of proper approach for pandas but it worked for what I need it.

```
elapsed = []
    tmp =[]

    for i in range (0, len(df)): 
        tmp = datetime.strptime(df.Time[i], '%H:%M:%S.%f %Y-%m-%d') 
        tmp_ms = tmp.microsecond
        tmp_s = tmp.second
        tmp_min  = tmp.minute
        tmp.append(tmp_min*60 + tmp_s + tmp_ms/1000000)

    for i in range (0, len(df)):     
        elapsed.append(tmp[i]-tmp[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
s.dt.second+s.dt.microsecond/10**6
```

For your example,

```
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(["03:32:57.565 2020-01-28",
                   "03:32:58.565 2020-01-28",
                   "03:32:59.566 2020-01-28",
                   "03:33:00.566 2020-01-28",
                   "03:33:01.569 2020-01-28",
                   "03:33:57.565 2020-01-28"]))
```

this produces

```
0    57.565
1    58.565
2    59.566
3     0.566
4     1.569
5    57.565
dtype: float64
```